# How can I understand : "I consider my plan to study"

Tags: grammar

How can I understand this? : "I consider my plan to study"

1. I am considering some plan to keep(or start) my studying.
2. I think my plan is to study.

Which one is closer to original meaning?

Comment: Where did you read this? What was the context? It's grammatically correct, but it's hard to imagine why anyone would ever say it.

Comment: I just wonder if it can be understood in different way. If there was a context, it might be not confusing. So, do you mean both are correct comprehension?

Comment: It just means what the words mean. "to consider" means to think about. A "plan to study" is a pre-chosen method of reading and thought intended to gain knowledge. But we hardly ever write just "I consider <something>". We almost always use this word as part of some more complex thought, like "I considered your plans, but decided to follow my own", or "Considering I have to be at work early tomorrow, I think I'll turn in now." or whatever. We almost never just tell someone we "consider" something and not expand on that thought.

Comment: One possibility is you might say "I consider my plan to study inadequate." or "I consider my plan to study to be too time consuming" or something like that.

Comment: I got your point. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Good explanation @ThePhoton